# Correct Syntax to Declare Foreign Key

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Book] (
   [Id]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
   [Auhor]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   [Name]   NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   [Price]  DECIMAL (18)  NOT NULL,
   [UserId] INT           NOT NULL,

   FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserProfile] ([UserId])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsedBook] (
   [Id]           INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
   [BookId]       INT          NOT NULL,
   [Email]        NCHAR (10)   NULL,
   [MobileNumber] VARCHAR (15) NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
   FOREIGN KEY (BookID) REFERENCES [dbo].[Book]([Id])
);
```

Can you please give me correct syntax for foreign key command in the `UsedBook` table? Because every time I tried to run this it gives me error

> SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[Book]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted.

And sorry for my english :)

Comment: The error message is crystal clear about the reason: your table `Book` doesn't have a **primary key** that you could reference! A FK can only reference a PK in a table (or sometimes, depending on your concrete database you're using, it can also reference a unique constraint). Your syntax is fine - the semantics are all wrong ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `[Id]` in your Book table into a primary key:

`[Id]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY`